# Read form file and send its contents to the clinet in GWT

Tags: gwt

I need to read form TXT file on the server side and send its contents to the client side to print in a label or any thing, i need to know where i place the TXT file is it on the server package or in WAR and how to code it?? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doens't really matter where you place the file. It must be on the server and a php script must be able to open the file. You can ready the text file the following way with php.
Then make a http request with GWT to that file.

*Read the file:*

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
?>
```

*Make http request:*

```
public class GetExample implements EntryPoint {
  public static final int STATUS_CODE_OK = 200;

  public static void doGet(String url) {
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);

    try {
      Request response = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
          // Code omitted for clarity
        }

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
          String content = response.getText();
        }
      });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
      // Code omitted for clarity
    }
  }

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    doGet("/");
  }
}
```

Comment: On your webserver. For example I have a webapplication and in the war directory I have another dir called php. In this folder I have all my php scripts. When I compile my GWT application I copy the whole war folder to a webserver.

Comment: I just tried it out and you can make a request to a txt file. So you don't really need the php script. Do in my example doGet("test.txt"); Place your test.txt file in the war folder where you can also find <yourproject>.html and <yourproject>.css After the request is completed the String content contains the content of the txt file.